# Get next month in Y-m-d format from any given Y-m-d

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to add a month to a date. I have tried many different things but keep coming up short. My most recent try is this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", $month[$i]));
```

This is a `var_dump` of `$months`. Note that the months are totally subject to change:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "2014-04-01" [1]=> string(10) "2014-05-01" }
```

I am looping through the `$months` like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($months); $i++) { //doing stuff }
```

where I have a query with a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE r.departure >= '".$months[$i]."' AND r.departure < '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day next month',$month[$i]))."'
```

What I am trying to do is limit each query to between a month and the next month.

Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someDate LIKE '%-08-%';`

Comment: That would work but I would need to tack off the `01` from the end of my `$months[$i]` string

Comment: Go ahead and make that an answer. I changed the way I brought in the date to make it `Y-m` instad of `Y-m-01` and used your query. It all works now.

Comment: Both current answers will ignore relevant portions of indices (your queries will be slow over large datasets).  The initial pattern shown in your `WHERE` clause is the best one (although you want prepared statement to avoid SQL Injection) - pretty much all RDBMSs have date-math functions for dates that work well on parameters - what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Well, I am doing is creating a report of advance deposits from the current month until there are no more deposits (customers can make a deposit months in advance like a flight booking or something). I first query to get all the months after the current month involved in the deposits. I then put all those months into an array and loop through it using the month as part of the `WHERE` clause you see.
Please elaborate on making it more efficient. I also have another [SQL issue if you're up for it ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051108/complex-mysql-join-with-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someDate LIKE '%-08-%';`

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this from MySQL itself:

```
WHERE YEAR(r.departure) = YEAR('".$months[$i]."') AND
MONTH(r.departure) = MONTH('".$months[$i]."')
```